# Connecting GFCI outlet to existing wire

Tags: electrical

I have a 15 amp wire (this wire had been powering a very low demand device) on a 20 amp fuse connected (spliced) in a junction box to 12 gage Romex.  I have wired the Romex to a 20amp GFCI receptacle.  The yellow light on the receptacle is on, but the receptacle will not reset. Is this due to the 15 amp wire? Yes, I plan on replacing the 12 gage 20 amp wire with 15 amp wire and 15 amp receptacle (only option because can't trace wire back to fuse), but I have trouble believe the 15 amp wire is the source of the problem for now.

Comment: the 14 gauge(15 amp) wire should not give the GFCI problems.  Mistake in connecting or a problem with the circuit will.  You are not allowed to have 14 gauge wire on a 20 amp circuit, but the easy fix is to change the 20 amp breaker/fuse to a 15 amp one and everything is good.

Comment: The function indicated by the light on GFCI receptacles is not consistent. The two obvious things is to check is to make sure you terminated the hot wires to the terminals marked "Line", and that you got the hot connected to the copper colored screw (the side with the short blade, and the white connected to silver colored screw (the side of the receptacle with the tall or t-shaped blade).

Comment: FWIW, the "low demand" device and 14awg wire and 20A breaker combo are bad because a short can start a fire on the wire before the breaker thinks about tripping. The devices and their normal draw aren't the issue.